# The function $f$, $f''(x) + f'(x) - e^x f(x) =0$ cannot have a non-negative maximum unless $f\equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function, satisfying

\begin{align}
f''(x) + f'(x) - e^x f(x) =0
\end{align}
for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to show that $f$ cannot have a non-negative maximum unless $f\equiv 0$.

I have no idea at this moment. My first trial is plugging $f(x) = e^{\alpha x} g(x)$ and find $\alpha$ and solution of $g(x)$ but this was not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your function is differentiable, if it has a maximum at $x_0$, say, then $f'(x_0)=0$. So
$$
f''(x_0)=e^{x_0}\,f(x_0). 
$$
If the maximum is positive, then $f(x_0)>0$, so the right-hand-side is positive: thus $f''(x_0)>0$, a contradiction.